# Hide "out of stock" products on home page only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My site has a few product categories, for example Tables, Chairs, Sofas and a Recently Sold category. I would like to:

- hide all out-of-stock products from the homepage (shop page)
- but still show them on the assigned category archives

Example:

- a sold table has been assigned the categories "Tables" and "Recently Sold". The product should not be shown on the homepage, but will be shown on the category page "Tables" and the category page "Recently Sold".
- a sold table has been assigned the category "Recently Sold". The product should only be shown on the category page "Recently Sold".

I had found a snippet somewhere years ago which worked perfectly. With the change of theme, it got lost. I have tried so many plugins and snippets but I just can't find a solution anymore.

Hope you guys can help :-) Thanks so much!

Comment: What you use to show products on front page? Improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the plugin Hide Out of Stock Products. This will let you adjust the settings to hide them.

If you wanted to do it programmatically, use the code below.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'hide_out_of_stock_products', 10, 2 );
function hide_out_of_stock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_front_page() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'   => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

This code will hide the out of stock products from the home page, but they will be seen on other pages.